# Boot Repair didn't work

Tags: boot

I face a problem 2 days now. I tried to install ubuntu in my computer and when I reboot my computer it says "No operation system found".
I followed that link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair but it still says the same. The link that they provided me in case it will not work is that http://paste2.org/cz5FK7x7.
Could you please help me and guide me what to do ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are in UEFI mode?  There is no legacy bootloader, so legacy mode should fail.

Comment: I have UEFI enabled. Is anything else I need to check ?